# Building Caffe: Failed to see hdf5.h

Tags: compiling, opencv, makefile, image-processing, caffe

Hello Caffe is a library for deeplearning. When trying to build that library under Ubuntu 15.04, the compilation fails with the message:

```
:~/App/caffe$ make all

PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/common_layers.hpp:10:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/vision_layers.hpp:10,
                 from src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:6:
./include/caffe/data_layers.hpp:9:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include "hdf5.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:512: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o] Error 1
```

The building failure seems to be Ubuntu specific. I have checked the different dependencies. I tried different workaround: writing the path of hdf5.h directly in the Makefile.config, building hdf5 from source...

Thanks for advices

Comment: Please [edit] you question to actually contain the entire question, thanks.

Comment: For those seeking an answer to this problem, the parallel discussion on the Caffe mailing list has solutions: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/cdyqjNpoFRY

Answer (score 26):

install `libhdf5-dev`

add patch to `libhdf5` in `Makefile.config`.

example: `INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/`

Comment: +1 Found this searching and it fixed the issue. @Jean-Pat, please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: This fixes the missing include but the compile just fails later because it can't find the libs.

Comment: @Alistair Buxton: I have made an addition to the answer, in order to show how to fix this issue, if it persists, even after updating the Makefile.config.

Comment: To me, this leads to another error:  
`AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:572: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
`

Comment: This change in the `Makefile.config` fixed my issue:  `LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial`